# Google API - update spreadsheet using PUT with PHP and Curl

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google's own example from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

They say:

To update the contents of an existing row, first retrieve the row to update, modify it as desired, and then send a PUT request, with the updated row in the message body, to the row's edit URL.

Be sure that the id value in the entry you PUT exactly matches the id of the existing entry. The edit URL is highlighted in the following row entry:

```
<entry gd:etag='"S0wCTlpIIip7ImA0X0QI"'>
  <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full/rowId</id>
  <updated>2006-11-17T18:23:45.173Z</updated>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006"
    term="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"/>
  <title type="text">Bingley</title>
  <content type="text">Hours: 10, Items: 2, IPM: 0.0033</content>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full/rowId"/>
  <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full/rowId/version"/>
  <gsx:name>Bingley</gsx:name>
  <gsx:hours>20</gsx:hours>
  <gsx:items>4</gsx:items>
  <gsx:ipm>0.0033</gsx:ipm>
</entry>
```

I've been attempting to send this info (using my own data, but exact same structure) with the following CURL:

```
$headers = array(
            "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $google_auth,
            "GData-Version: 3.0",
            "Content-Type: application/atom+xml",
            "If-Match: *",
            );
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/$feed/0/private/full/$row_id");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
            echo $response;
```

It seems that the XML is malformed which is odd as it comes right from Google's example and I get the same response when retrieving a list feed from my own spreadsheets. How do I correct and are there any other issues?

When I paste this xml into http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html, I receive an error that

```
Unable to parse any XML input. org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: The prefix "gd" for attribute "gd:etag" associated with an element type "entry" is not bound.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no real responses....but I finally got it working. Hopefully this helps someone else. The idea is you need to use the namespaces which are retrieved with the feed.

So the XML should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" gd:etag="&quot;S0wCTlpIIip7ImA0X0QI&quot;">
   <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full/rowId</id>
   <updated>2006-11-17T18:23:45.173Z</updated>
   <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006" term="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list" />
   <title type="text">Bingley</title>
   <content type="text">Hours: 10, Items: 2, IPM: 0.0033</content>
   <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full/rowId" />
   <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full/rowId/version" />
   <gsx:name>Bingley</gsx:name>
   <gsx:hours>20</gsx:hours>
   <gsx:items>4</gsx:items>
   <gsx:ipm>0.0033</gsx:ipm>
</entry>
```

And the CURL should look like:

```
$headers = array(
            "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $google_auth, //google_auth retrieved earlier
            "GData-Version: 3.0",
            "Content-Type: application/atom+xml",
            "If-Match: *",
            );

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/$feed/0/private/full/$id"); //feed is obtained from spreadsheet url and id can be obtained by retrieving list feed
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        echo $response;
```

Comment: But why do you insert the timestamp in the <updated> tag?  Shouldn't that be something that the Google's servers respond with?

Comment: You were right about the xmlns attributes needing to be in the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve and update a proper custom XML instead of a generic Atom XML doc, then you can try APISpark PaaS which has a wrapper for GSpreadsheets that can create and host a custom web API.

See tutorial: https://apispark.com/docs/tutorials/google-spreadsheet

Comment: That does look interesting, although a quick glance only makes mention of retrieving or adding new data. I'm sure there is something in there about updating and deleting.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the Web API created at the end of the tutorial, it has HTTP PUT (for update) and DELETE methods for this.

Answer (score 0):

This should be help to you

```
$accessToken = $ACCESS_TOKEN;

$key = $SPREADSHEET_ID;
$sheetId = $SHEET_ID;

$editUrl = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/$key/$sheetId/private/full/R2C4?access_token=$accessToken";

$entry = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gs="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006"><id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/'.$key.'/'.$sheetId.'/private/full/R2C4</id><link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/'.$key.'/'.$sheetId.'/private/full/R2C4"/><gs:cell row="2" col="4" inputValue="Enter_Value_Here">Enter_Value_Here</gs:cell></entry>';

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $editUrl );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/atom+xml','If-Match: *','Content-length: ' . strlen($entry)));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $entry );

$content = curl_exec($ch);

if($content === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch)."<br>";
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors <br>';
    $information = curl_getinfo($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```